# How do you handle multiple versions of same jar?

Tags: maven, ant, ivy

I use Apache_Gora_0.2.1 and Apache Nutch_2.1 .

- Nutch depends on Gora.
- Gora have modules gora-core and gora-hbase.
- gora-hbase depends on gora-core.
- All the modules of Gora use avro_1.3.3.jar . I want to use avro_1.3.3.jar for gora-core and avro_1.5.3.jar for gora-hbase .
- I successfully compiled Gora via Maven and I successfully compiled Nutch via Ant and Ivy.

Then seems to be two versions in the Nutch classpath (avro.1.3.3.jar and avro.1.5.3.jar). If I exclude avro_1.5.3.jar via ivy.xml, gora-hbase don't use avro.1.5.3.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the situation when you have in the classpath same jars with different versions.
To solve your problem you need to find version of Apache_Gora_0.2.1 and Apache Nutch_2.1 that uses the similar versions of avro. 
Try do use Apache Nutch_1.6, since Apache_Gora_0.2.1 is the latest version.
Then, you exclude the lowest version and you solve your problem.

Comment: I should try Apache Nutch_2.1. Because Nutch_1.6 don't support hbase.

Comment: You can accepts and promote my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to downgrade Nutch to 2.0 because this works with avro 1.3.3.
If I am not wrong, gora-hbase does not work with avro 1.5.3, but 1.3.3.

At the same time, tell that gora-hbase only uses avro to serialize values... why do you need it to use avro 1.5.3?

Comment: Because, I must use hbase 0.94.5 and this hbase version support avro 1.5.3 , doesn't support 1.3.3 .

Comment: I think that, sadly, Gora is not compatible with HBase 0.94.5 for that reason. Hold on, hopefully will be updates soon. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/gora-user/201304.mbox/%3CCAJVBNiGWiLGh8mUZXU%2BMyqtRM5hddhrvqkX22jSA_kAg%2BKMsJQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E